# MPMoviePlayerController missing controls when rotating and fullscreening after play

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape-portrait

So here is the scenario:

I have an `MPMoviePlayerController` that can be played inside the screen, but there is a nice "FullScreen" default button.
(I need both ways so I can't use `MPMoviePlayerViewController`)

My app is mostly forced to portrait, but when switching to fullscreen I allow landscape in the following manner:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[VideoLandscapeShared sharedMySingleton] setIsRotate:true];
}
```

And in AppDelegate:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if ([VideoLandscapeShared sharedMySingleton].isRotate)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

This is mostly OK. Now for the weird problem:

On iOS8 only, when I start playing a video on portrait inside the view, turn the screen over to landscape (video and view stays put), and than click the fullscreen button (in the player) - the video goes to fullscreen but without the controls (so the user can't click Done)

This doesn't happen on iOS7.

Any clues where to investigate how to fix it?

**Edit:**

Tried to bypass the problem by adding a `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` event observer and doing `setFullscreen:false` but the event is not firing when the weird case happens :(

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ios8PlaybackFinished:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

- (void)ios8PlaybackFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = (MPMoviePlayerController *)[notification object];
    [player setFullscreen:false animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I displayed MPMoviePlayerViewController in a container view on the iPad. If i clicked the full screen button - the controls were still visible. If I rotated whilst in full screen, the buttons disappeared and I was unable to close the video.

I then swapped it out for AVPlayerViewController, but this also had the same problem and I deduced that it was probably because I wasn't using the view controller containment methods. So I added this code and it solved my problems:

```
// Create the AVPlayerViewControllers
self.avPlayerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

// Create the video player 
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
self.avPlayerController.player = player;

// Setup where it will appear on my view    
self.avPlayerController.view.frame = self.moviePlayerContainer.bounds;

// Add it to my container
[self.moviePlayerContainer addSubview:self.avPlayerController.view];

// Animate it's appearance and do the container dance
self.avPlayerController.view.alpha = 0.0;     
[self.parentViewController addChildViewController:self.avPlayerController];
[self.avPlayerController willMoveToParentViewController:self.parentViewController];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.avPlayerController.view.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [player play];
    [self.avPlayerController didMoveToParentViewController:self.avPlayerController];
}];
```

Then remember to do the reverse dance, and remove it properly when finished:

```
[self.avPlayerController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.avPlayerController.view.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.avPlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.avPlayerController = nil;
    [self.avPlayerController removeFromParentViewController];
}];
```

You might be able to apply the same principles using MPMoviePlayerViewController (instead of MPMoviePlayerController), but I haven't tried.